How did the C64 bitmap layout save transistors?
The Commodore 64 bitmap mode video memory layout is, from a programmer's viewpoint, odd; instead of a linear sequence of bytes, the first 8 bytes are stacked vertically, then the next 8, and so on.
It is said e.g. in https://spectrum.ieee.org/commodore-64 that "this mimics the way that pixels for the character set are laid out... permitting the same circuitry to be used for both modes."
Okay, the mimicry looks visually reasonable if you look at a diagram of the layout, but the more I think about how to implement it, the more it doesn't seem to make sense. It seems to me the character mode would need to work this way:

Increment the video memory pointer 40 times, each time reading character cell, then performing the font lookup.
At end of 7/8 of scan lines, subtract 40 from the video memory pointer. (Or restore it to the beginning of the line from a saved copy, whichever is cheaper.)

Then the most obvious way for the bitmap mode to work is:

Same, except don't do the font lookup.
Don't subtract 40/restore.

That would give a linear layout, with no additions to the character mode circuitry except a couple of "don't"s.
How does it actually work, that saves hardware compared to the above apparently minimal way? What am I missing?

Without any detailed insight of the actual video logic, I can think of the usage of already existing horizontal and vertical counters to use as "character code" provider, and then the video memory is used instead of the font memory. This can actually lead to some minimum logic.


this mimics the way that pixels for the character set are laid out... permitting the same circuitry to be used for both modes.

That is the case. The circuitry does use the address of the character cell first, (it has to, since the Color RAM and Screen RAM are both read from this address) and then from this address, the VIC-II derives the address of the bitmap, and this arrangement does save some transistors.
Now, the character cell only counts to 1000, and that's not enough to span an 8K bitmap, of course. So the fourteen-bit address of the byte that the VIC-II needs to load into its shift register and clock out as pixels, need to be augmented by bits derived from other places, to make it up to fourteen bits.
If you lay this address out, you will see that bit 13 of the address is always bit 3 of $d018, and bits 0-2 of the address are always bits 0-2 of RASTER. That leaves ten bits in between. This space is occupied by:

Either, another two bits from $d018, and the eight bits from the screencode (text mode),
Or, the ten bit character cell address (bitmap mode).

So this bitmap mode is like making a font that has 1000 characters in it, and substituting the screencode by its address: the hardware is exactly the same, except that a ten-bit, two-to-one multiplexer is slipped in while generating the address of the bitmap.

How does it actually work, that saves hardware compared to the above apparently minimal way? What am I missing?

You could be missing the fact that the counter is ten bits, and that's where the saving is. If I understand your proposed solution as described in OP correctly, it would require a thirteen bit counter.

You're right, my solution would indeed require a 13 bit counter, that's what I was missing. Thanks!

@rwallace also don't forget that you need to read the screen ram as well, since that contains color information, so your point "Same, except don't do the font lookup." doesn't quite work
